Правильно ли здесь составлено предложение?

Телефон - вещь хорошая, имеет много полезных фишек и удобств.

Правильно ли здесь составлено предложение? Если есть ошибки, то почему?

в целом ошибок нет, но "хорошая" я бы заменил на "полезная".

@Буратино, а дефис что тут забыл? А потом: по вашему мнению, в целом, предложений с одинаковыми словами должно быть больше?

@shampar "Телефон - (это) вещь хорошая. Телефон - это такое." Не понял про "должно быть больше", что должно быть больше, как это? Я вообще не вижу повторяющихся или одинаковых слов и тавтологии в этом предложении. Это не значит, что стилистически оно совершенно, но тавтологии тут нет, или есть?


Дефис вместо тире не видите (и в комментарии тоже)? 2. Вводя ещё одно слово (я бы заменил на "полезная" — Б.), не понимаете, что их будет вдвое больше? На эти вопросы можно не отвечать. Ответьте на заданный И. Г.


Я уж отвечу, а то зря старались что ли?) "Дефис вместо тире не видите (и в комментарии тоже)?" - вижу, но разве это влияет на правильность написания? На клавиатуре нет тире, только дефис. "Полезная, полезная" - понял) да, я что-то не то иногда вижу, "хорошее" заменить на "полезная", а второе "полезная" убрать) - так лучше? Да, тут я ерунду написал, бывает). На вопрос я ответил: предложение в целом правильно составлено, но довольно бессодержательно. Если править такое предложение, то пропадёт его бессодержательность, так что я бы оставил всё как есть. И вообще, зря стал поправлять, как видите)

Правильно:
Телефон вещь хорОшая, имеет много полезных фишек и удОбств.
Пояснение
Стиль речи разговорный.  При инверсии (вещь хорОшая) тире становится необязательным, что связано со смещением логического ударения на определение.
Бессоюзная связь обозначена запятой, точка с запятой там ни к чему.
Сравнить: Телефон — хорошая вещь, имеет много полезных фишек и удОбств. Тире ставится по обычным правилам.

Правильно ли здесь составлено предложение?
Я бы немного поменял предложение:
Телефон — хорошая вещь, которая имеет много полезных фишек и удобств.
ИЛИ
Телефон — хорошая вещь, имеющая много полезных фишек и удобств.
ИЛИ
Телефон — хорошая вещь; имеет много полезных фишек и удобств.
